# Gitflow feature folder contains weird characters

Tags: git, git-flow

When trying to create a feature branch git flow seems to think my feature folder has loads of weird chars in it:

```bsh
git flow feature start "#2167-_Path_issues_caused_by_base-href_being_overwritten_in_JS"
fatal: 'feature?[1;5D?[1;5D?[D?[D?[D?[D?[D/feature#2167-_Path_issues_caused_by_base-href_being_overwritten_in_JS' is not a valid branch name.
Fatal: Could not create feature branch 'fe/feature#2167-_Path_issues_caused_by_base-href_being_overwritten_in_JS'.
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, Is there a setting somewhere for it?

Comment: You were pushing arrow keys on your keyboard, and they sent these escape sequences. ESC [ <number> D is the right-arrow function. To fix it, stop pressing the arrow keys.

Comment: Must have been doing that without realising. Wow, now I feel stupid. Thanks though :)